# Reading data from SQL Server and formatting it

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database with a table `QC` and columns `A, B, C, D, E, 
Comment`.

What I am trying to do is to read the data from the columns and display it in a label. But there is not always data in all columns.

Expected output is:

```
2.5|2.1
```

if there is data only in A and B column. But I get:

```
2.5|2.1| |||||
```

This is my code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [TableQC] ORDER BY id DESC", conn);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

string temp = "";
string temp1 = "";

while (reader.Read())
{
    temp += reader["A"].ToString() + "|";
    temp += reader["B"].ToString() + "|";
    temp += reader["C"].ToString() + "|";
    temp += reader["D"].ToString() + "|";
    temp += reader["E"].ToString() + "|";
    temp1 += reader["Comment"].ToString();
    //temp += "<br/>";
}
conn.Close();

label1.Text = temp;
label2.Text = temp1;
```

Comment: If there is no data then don't concatenate it. You can test it by `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(reader["C"].ToString()) == true`

Comment: Some word of advice: Separate your data access code from presentation logic. Since it looks like you are building a web app, just put your result in a collection (DataTable) and bind it to some repeater control for display instead of concatenating output html like back in ASP Classic times.

Comment: Mong Zhu, when i add your part like it is it ask me to ass at end ; when i add it i get error  Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: Filburt, i am newbie. I have no idea what you are saying. Yes, i am trying to build web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mong Zhu pointed out, check while reading the column values:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.GetString("A")))
```

This will test each column for null value and replace it with an empty string.

To avoid a dangling `|` delimiter at the end, work with an array of strings you the `Join()`

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    // create an array big enough to hold all columns
    object[] qc = new object[reader.FieldCount];

    // iterate over all columns of your reader
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        if (reader[i] == reader["Comment"])
        {
            label2.Text = reader.GetSqlString(i).IsNull ? null : reader.GetSqlString(i).Value;
        }
        else
        {
            // add to array
            qc[i] = reader.GetValue(i);
        }
    }

    label1.Text = string.Join("|", qc.OfType<string>());
}
```

However it seems to didn't tell the actual data type of columns A, B, etc. and assuming them to be of string/character data type turned out to be false.

Depending on your actual data types, you will have to edit the filtering Linq query to the actual type like `qc.OfType<decimal>()` or only filter for null values like `qc.Where(v => !(v is DBNull))`.

Comment: Filburt, the second way remove the delimiter that i need to use. Is there other way how to add that delimiter | ?

Comment: This is doing the job, but the output is not as i wish. It look like this: 2.5|2.3| and if i put in A,B and D column it looks like this: 2.5|2.3| |2.2| the output that i need is like: 2.5|2.3  if there is only in A and B, but if there is in D, like: 2.5|2.3|2.2 is there a way hot to do this?

Comment: @Filburt what is sdr? what king of variable it is ?

Comment: Sorry it took so many edits - looks like I tried to optimize too much in one go.

Comment: @Filburt i get error System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.' here: qc[i] = reader.GetString(i);

Comment: This is because you have an int column `id` you didn't mention but is visible in the `ORDER BY` clause. Fix this by replacing `SELECT TOP 1 *` with `SELECT TOP 1 A, B, C, D, E, Comment` in your query to actually select the columns you claim to have.

Comment: @Filburt i am sorry that i forgot to mention that, i made the fix but now i have this: System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'

Comment: My bad, using either `GetString` or `GetSqlString` you still need to check for `DbNull`.

Comment: @Filburt System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.' now i have this. Also, i mention in the beginning the A,B,C,D,E goes to label1, and Comment goes to label 2.

Comment: Before we enter into an extended loop of editing and guessing please add the full schema information of your table to your post.

Comment: @Filburt, i have table called TableQC with columns  ID, A,B,C,D,E,F,G,Coment. ID column is INT, A,B,C,D,E,F,G are FLOAT and Comment column is nvarchar(300). i have 2 labes(1,2). In label 1 i need to show only A,B,C,D,E,F,G in format: 2.5|2.3|1.5 in label2 i need to show only Comment column. ID column i use only to Select TOP1 from TableQC.

Comment: @StojanKocev For FLOAT database types, change the filter to `.OfType<double>()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the query.  Basically you want `concat_ws()`, but that is not available in SQL Server.  Instead:

```
SELECT TOP 1 STUFF( (COALESCE('|' + A, '') +
                     COALESCE('|' + B, '') +
                     COALESCE('|' + C, '') +
                     COALESCE('|' + D, '') +
                     COALESCE('|' + E, '') +
                     COALESCE('|' + Comment, '')
                    ), 1, 1, ''
                  ) as abcde

FROM [TableQC]
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: @Filburt . . . No, it does not.  This is the most convenient way of implementing `concat_ws()` in SQL Server that I know of.

Comment: @Filburt . . . Of course it will.  That is why the `STUFF()` removes it.

Comment: Jeez, it sure gets late for me - I totally ignored that `STUFF`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for helping me and resolving my problem. This is the code that works for me:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [TableQC] ORDER BY id DESC", conn);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    // create an array big enough to hold all columns
    object[] qc = new object[reader.FieldCount];

    // iterate over all columns of your reader
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        if (reader[i] == reader["Comment"])
        {
            lblMessage1.Text = reader.GetSqlString(i).IsNull ? null : reader.GetSqlString(i).Value;
        }
        else
        {
            // add to array
            qc[i] = reader.GetValue(i);
        }
    }

    lblMessage.Text = string.Join("|", qc.OfType<double>());
}

conn.Close();
```

Thanks you a lot once more time.